# Who participated in the Gran Sasso raid/Operation Eiche?

Tags: world-war-two, military, nazi-germany

I am looking for a list of all soldiers who participated in the [Gran Sasso raid/Operation Eiche](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gran_Sasso_raid).

The Wikipedia list only the 4 who received Knight's Cross, and the 9 with German Cross in Gold.

But who were the rest? Those who received the Iron Cross (EK I or EK II)? Or those who had fallen (if there were any)?

Perhaps there is a way to find out who were the members of Fallschirmjäger-Lehr-Bataillon of the 2. Fallschirmjägerdivision, 1/FJR 7; SS-Sonderverband z.b.V. Friedenthal in September 1943?